# How to overlay byte[50] and UInt16[25] arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, overlay

I need to have both Byte and Word(UInt16) representation of the same data, or in other words 2 arrays - say `byte[50]` and `UInt16[25]` - at the same address.
A change in one to be automatically reflected in the other.
For example if I write 260 to `WordArray[1]`, `ByteArray[2]` to become 4 and `ByteArray[3]` to become 1. Then I write 3 to `ByteArray[3]`, and `WordArray[1]` becomes 772.

Comment: Use [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] to create a union.

Comment: that's OK for Int, byte etc. variables but doesn't work for arrays.

Comment: It is fine for arrays as well, you just can't overlap a reference type with a value type.  Not what you are asking for so no problem.

Comment: could you please post some hint how to use it with arrays? Anything I try ends with  
------
System.TypeLoadException
------ 
  Message=Could not load type 'testStruct' from.... because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ??? this explains how to create an example. I'm asking whether  something is possible, and if yes - how to do it. Obviously creating an example of what I don't know would be idiotic. If you are sure it can't be done - say it can't be done. Otherwise, if you don't know - no need to reply. If interested, just wait someone who knows to reply.